# Difference between "tune" and "adjust" (in case of "parameter")

Tags: differences

I was wondering if there is a difference between *tuning a parameter* and *adjusting a parameter*. Could there be a slight difference between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider *tuning* a type of *adjustment.*  Typically making small changes in the parameter to achieve a desired result or effect.

Comment: So, you mean adjustment is rougher than tuning, right?

Comment: No, I mean *tuning* is a subset of *adjustment,* a type of adjustment.

Comment: Tuning is a process which involves a series of adjustments each followed by an evaluation. It's what you do when you don't have an exact formula for how much to adjust something for a desired effect, or when there are complex interactions between parameters. "We rented 2 hours of track time to tune the suspension on the car."